# elasticsearch client thread safety

Tags: elasticsearch

I am writting a query plugin, that will build the query for given keywords and pass it to elastic search client to process.

My handler class extends BaseRestHandler, and I've the Client object being injected in my handler's constructor.

```
@Inject
protected QueryHandler(Settings settings, Client client, RestController controller) {
    super(settings, client);
    controller.registerHandler(GET, "/_query/{queryBuilder}", this);
}
```

I was wondering if it's thread safe to use the same client object in handleRequest() method?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like any implementation of the client is thread safe. Check out @kimchy's answer here: http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Is-NodeClient-thread-safe-td2816264.html

Comment: In a app that uses a thread pool (size not more than 10) that does local IO too, will it be more performant (if those threads never die and are reused), to use a client per thread?